# Как распаковать словарь в python?

Tags: python

**Есть словарь:**

```
{'История': [3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2], 
'Русский язык': [5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4], 
'Литература': [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5], 
'Информатика': [3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4],
'Алгебра и начала математического анализа': [5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5], 
'Химия': [4, 5, 5, 5, 4], 
'Обществознание': [5, 5, 5], 
'Биология': [5, 5, 5, 4, 3], 
'География': [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4], 
'Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности': [5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4], 
'Вероятность и статистика': [3, 4, 5], 
'Физическая культура': [3, 5, 4, 5, 3], 
'Геометрия': [5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5], 
'Иностранный язык': [4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3], 
'Физика': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3]}
```

Нужно его распаковать! Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?
Например:
**Физика: 5 5 5 5 5 4 3**
Но только так, чтобы были все предметы, которые находятся в словаре!

Comment: Что значит «распаковать»? Что конкретно вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Я хочу получить название предмета (ключ в словаре) и оценки (список) Например, Физика: 5 5 5 5 5 4 3. Но только так, чтобы были все предметы, которые находятся в словаре!

Comment: *Распаковкой* в Python называется не совсем то, о чём вы пишите: https://fullstacker.ru/raspakovka-slovarey-v-python-luchshie-metody-i-praktiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {'История': [3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2], 
'Русский язык': [5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4], 
'Литература': [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5], 
'Информатика': [3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4],
'Алгебра и начала математического анализа': [5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5], 
'Химия': [4, 5, 5, 5, 4], 
'Обществознание': [5, 5, 5], 
'Биология': [5, 5, 5, 4, 3], 
'География': [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4], 
'Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности': [5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4], 
'Вероятность и статистика': [3, 4, 5], 
'Физическая культура': [3, 5, 4, 5, 3], 
'Геометрия': [5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5], 
'Иностранный язык': [4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3], 
'Физика': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3]}

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f'{k}:', *v)
```

> ```
> История: 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 5 4 3 4 2
> Русский язык: 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 5 5 4
> Литература: 5 4 5 4 5 5 4 4 4 5
> Информатика: 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 4 3 4 5 3 5 5 4 3 3 4 5 5 4
> Алгебра и начала математического анализа: 5 4 4 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 5 5 4 5
> Химия: 4 5 5 5 4
> Обществознание: 5 5 5
> Биология: 5 5 5 4 3
> География: 5 5 5 2 5 4
> Основы безопасности жизнедеятельности: 5 5 5 5 4 4
> Вероятность и статистика: 3 4 5
> Физическая культура: 3 5 4 5 3
> Геометрия: 5 5 4 4 5 4 4 5 5
> Иностранный язык: 4 4 3 4 5 4 3 3
> Физика: 5 5 5 5 5 4 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_person(name, age):
    print(f"Name: {name}, Age: {age}")

people_dicts = [{"name": "John", "age": 25}, {"name": "Jane", "age": 30}]

for person_dict in people_dicts:
    print_person(**person_dict)
 
#Name: John, Age: 25
#Name: Jane, Age: 30
```

Здесь мы проходим по списку словарей `people_dicts`, и каждый словарь распаковывается и передается в функцию `print_person()` в виде именованных аргументов

Comment: Я понимаю, как выводить такого рода словари, но мой словарь может постоянно менять свои ключи и от этого такая программа становится не практичной

Comment: Не становится. Здесь ни в одном месте не указан ни один ключ.